# Extend an entity class in JPA throws Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list' error

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy=InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)  
public class Person {    
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "PERSON_ID")
    private Long personId;

    @Column(name = "FIRSTNAME")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name = "LASTNAME")
    private String lastname;

    // Constructors and Getter/Setter methods, 
}
```

Employee class extends Person

```
@Entity    
public class Employee extends Person {

    @Transient
    private Date joiningDate;   


    // Copy Constructors and Getter/Setter methods, 
}
```

The Employee class has only a transient object So I am not sure about using of @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorValue, When i tried without using Discriminator that throws error

```
session.save(employee);
```

I am trying to save Employee object that throws Unknown column 'DTYPE' in 'field list' error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Mapping Multiple Classes to a Table in Hibernate, Without a DTYPE Column](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4868124/mapping-multiple-classes-to-a-table-in-hibernate-without-a-dtype-column)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JPA Mapping with basic class inheritance](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26655846/jpa-mapping-with-basic-class-inheritance)

Comment: Employee class only has a transient object, So  not sue about @DiscriminatorColumn and DiscriminaorValue

Comment: You forgot to add this column into the database schema.

Answer (score 6):

I have encountered the same issue using EclipseLink and I have tried to use @discriminator annotation ... without success
because in this solution, a specific column must be added in 2 tables.

I don't have the possibility to add columns in tables, so I have found following solution :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS) 
public class Person {
```

I have just changed inheritance type from SINGLE_TABLE to TABLE_PER_CLASS

I have found useful explanation on [Thoughts on Java](https://www.thoughts-on-java.org/complete-guide-inheritance-strategies-jpa-hibernate/)

Just for information, my 2 tables are in reality 1 table and a view on same table with 2 or 3 joins.

Answer (score 3):

You should use @DiscriminatorColumn and @DiscriminatorValue. You can find a good example [here](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/hibernate-inheritence-table-per-hierarchy-mapping/).

Comment: In my Employee class, I have only one Transient attribute, no other repeated columns, So in this case, I am not sure about DiscriminatorColumn

Comment: I think it does not matter. Hibernate may require to know which value should save into DTYPE by each class into the hierarchy

Answer (score 0):

`D_TYPE` is basically name of your child class.

Let's suppose you have:

- Abstract Employee(id, name);
- class FullTimeEmployee extends Employee(Double salary)
- with Inheritence.SINGLE_TABLE strategy.

A table employee will be created with these columns

```
Employee (D_TYPE, id, name, salary)
```

where `D_TYPE` will be name of your child classes.

```
employeeRepository.insert(Employee emp);
```

where you can pass emp as `new FullTimeEmployee(id, name, salary);`

After insert it will automatically populate `d_type` as Full_Time_Employee

If you want to change the name of `D_TYPE` column use
`@DiscriminatorColumn(name="customizedNameofD_TYPE")`

Just FYI: mostly used strategy is `InheritanceType.JOINED`

Answer (score -1):

Persist child entity rather than persisting parent entity.

```
@MappedSuperclass
public class Person {
```

And

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "PERSON")
public class Employee extends Person {
```

This should resolve your issue.